# Linux grep how to treat all lines as a big line for regex?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

An example, test.txt:

```
This is bad, real bad!
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://tips.cf"
xmlns:impl="http://tips.cf" xmlns:intf="http://tips.cf"
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
```

I have a regex: `^<\?xml.*\?>`.

`grep` match as line by line. So this regex can have a match(the second line).

But I want to make grep treat the lines as a big line, and couldn't have a match, because it is not startswith `<?xml`.

I tried:

```
grep -P -z -- '^<\?xml.*\?>' test.txt
```

use `-z` but it still match the second line.

Is there a way to use `grep` to make it unmatch, or there is another regex command line tool?

Comment: `^` matches the start of a line (ie: the position after a newline sequence or the start of the string), not only the start of the string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte match newline should for multiple mode? and I have used `-z` to change EOL

Comment: Drop `-P and -z`!  `grep '^<?xml.*?>' test`  work fine

Comment: @F.Hauri: the goal is to make the pattern fail when there's no match at the start of the string.

Comment: @F.Hauri Why basic-regexp can work but perl-regexp could not?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte what do you mean when you write *string*? line, bloc ?

Comment: @TankyWoo perl don't use escape in same manner. And under PerlRe,  `?` is a *quantifier* wich mean *Match 1 or 0 times*

Comment: @F.Hauri , "under PerlRe, ? is a quantifier wich mean Match 1 or 0 times" is there a document?

Comment: `man -P"less +/'Match 1 or 0'" perlre`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `\A` instead of anchor `^` then it will fail the match:

```
# finds no match
grep -Pz -- '\A<\?xml.*\?>' file
```

This `grep` in a multiline string `^` matches at the start of every line but `\A` matches at the real start of input.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the lines to a big line by `xargs` before applying the regex:

```
# no match returns
cat test.txt | xargs | grep '^<?xml.*?>'
```

[Check for more usage on `xargs`](http://tecadmin.net/xargs-command-in-linux-with-example/#)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but if you want `grep` to treat all the lines as a single line, you can replace all the linefeeds in `test.txt` with spaces before passing it into `grep`, like this:

```
grep "pattern"  <( tr '\n' ' ' < test.txt)
```

Your original file will remain unaffected, the translation of linefeeds to spaces happens *"on-the-fly"*.

Comment: Don't fork if possible! You could add `\n` in your pattern, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35584470/1765658)!

Comment: @F.Hauri What's the problem with forking? Could you explain please?

Comment: A fork implie resources for a sub-process. If you could do same job with or without fork, don't. (regardless of parallisation for strong jobs.)

Comment: @F.Hauri I doubt a few tens of milliseconds to create a process are that critical on a modern multi-core machine if it makes the code easy to understand - most of the time they sit idle :-)

Comment: You could try to compare this: `time for ((i=1000;i--;));do grep -Pz '\A<\?xml.*\?>' test.txt;done` (On my computer: ~1.3sec) with this `time for ((i=1000;i--;));do grep -Pz '^<\?xml.*\?>'  <( tr '\n' ' ' < test.txt);done` (on my computer: ~2,7sec). Using useless fork take twice time!

Comment: But you're maybe right: while today, we could use a lot of power, why care?

Answer (score 0):

#### `grep` pattern containing newline ([bash](/questions/tagged/bash): `$'\n'`)

Try this:

```
grep -Pz '\AThis.*\n<\?xml.*\?>' test.txt
```

, this

```
grep -Pz '<\?xml.*\?>' test.txt
```

, this

```
grep -Pz '^<\?xml.*\?>' test.txt
```

and this

```
grep -Pz '\A<\?xml.*\?>' test.txt
```

or this

```
grep -z $'^This.*\n<\\?xml.*\\?>' test.txt
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain the last case? and `<\\?xml.*\\?>` doesn't include `<?`

Comment: on last command, I use `$'...'` wich is *bashism* developped by bash **before** running `grep`.  In this, `\\` is a single backslash (escaped). Than under grep, `?` match 0 or 1 time previous char, if not escaped. so `<\?` is same than `<?` and `$'<\\?'` is same too.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you want but maybe it's:

```
awk -v RS='<[?]xml.*[?]>' '$0=RT' file
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
This is bad, real bad!
<?xml
        version="1.0"
                encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://tips.cf"
xmlns:impl="http://tips.cf" xmlns:intf="http://tips.cf"
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"

$ awk -v RS='<[?]xml.*[?]>' '$0=RT' file         
<?xml
        version="1.0"
                encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT. With other awks it'd be:

```
$ awk '{rec = rec $0 RS} END{ if (match(rec,/<[?]xml.*[?]>/)) print substr(rec,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file   
<?xml
        version="1.0"
                encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```